# Finite integrals domains of same cardinality being equal as groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let R be a finite Integral domain.

Prove that is S is anther Finite integral domain with the same number of elements as R then $R\cong S $ as groups.

I guess we know they have the same number of elements? 
if we knew that o(R)= prime could we just define an isomorphism between both to the group $\mathbb{Z_p} $ ?

Comment: Also note that a finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: Sorry i corrected it they should have the same number of elements or it obviously is nonsense

Comment: Is there only one field of a specfic order? i thought there was more than one if the order wasnt prime?

Comment: @Faust For every prime power $q$ there is precisely one field of order $q$, up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $R$ is a finite integral domain, then $R$ is a finite field containing $\mathbb F_p$ and so is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: Sorry im not familiar with any finite dimensional vector spaces only infinite ones ill have to look up what your hint means.

Comment: You are not familiar with finite-dimensional vector spaces, but with infinite dimensional? I do not believe a word of what you are saying...

Comment: Sorry i meant im not familiar with any vector space that has a finite number of elements. i realize now my sentence is nonsense ^^

Comment: But when you did linear algebra, I guess you just called the field $K$ or $F$ or whatever? And you definitely showed that any $K$-vector space of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $K^n$. So where is the problem?

Comment: in linear algebra we never did such a thing i have only ever taken an intro class but i will try looking up the result you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

A finite integral domain is a field and finite fields with the same number of elements are even isomorphic as fields, so in particular there additive groups are isomorphic as groups.

But of course, it is easier to show only the latter:

You should show that $R$ contains $\mathbb F_p$ for some $p$ and thus is a $\mathbb F_p$-vector space. Using basic linear algebra, you get $R \cong (\mathbb F_p)^n$ as vector spaces. In particular this is an isomorphism of groups and you are done.

Comment: So R is a ring with o(R) =p^n for some n and some prime p?

Comment: Yes, this also follows from the proof.